# Aero Glass on windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, aero, dll

Hi I have been trying to get Aero Glass effect on Windows 8.1.

In windows 8 I have been using Aero Glass software from here http://glass8.berlios.de/download.html

But on windows 8.1 I can't use the one made for windows 8 however they do have a version for windows 8.1 but they say

> You still need to manually download symbols for udwm.dll, dwmcore.dll and dwm.exe else it won't work

So where I can get those dll and exe files which matches the Aero Glass?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the Windows 8.1 SDK and run this cmd:

```
MKDIR %userprofile%\appdata\local\temp\dlls

XCOPY "C:\Windows\System32\dwm.exe" %userprofile%\appdata\local\temp\dlls
XCOPY "C:\Windows\System32\dwmcore.dll" %userprofile%\appdata\local\temp\dlls
XCOPY "C:\Windows\System32\uDWM.dll" %userprofile%\appdata\local\temp\dlls

SYMCHK /r %userprofile%\appdata\local\temp\dlls /s SRV*C:\AeroGlass\symbols\*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

RD /S /Q "%userprofile%\appdata\local\temp\dlls"
```

to get the PDBs.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?What happens when i run them in Command prompt?PDB?

Comment: a PDB is the debug data (symbols) that you need to use Aero. The CMD copies the DWM exe and DLLs to a temp folder and downloads the PDB files with the help of the tool symchk.